# Three series LED arrays in parallel, resistor value?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

i know this is possible but not sure how to work out the resistor value needed... I should point out that I am re-using a PCB that has had all the components removed.

I need 15 LEDs in 3 parallel circuits, each circuit having 5 LEDs in series.
The 3 parallel circuits share 1 current limiting resistor between them.

```
    |-->-->-->-->-->--|
    |                 |
+ --|-->-->-->-->-->--|--/\/\/---
    |                 |
    |-->-->-->-->-->--|
```

Assuming 12v 2v forward voltage and 30mA, I know the resistor required would be 68 ohm.
Am I correct in assuming the resistor I need would still be 68 ohm?

Comment: don't use common resistor between parallel led paths UNLESS there is a smaller resistor per leg to mitigate the NTC of PN junctions

Comment: Use three 68R resistors not one.

Answer (score 5):

If you use ONE shared resistor it needs to be about (12-(5x2))/.030/3 =~~ 22R
BUT this is a bad idea as the 3 strings will not current share well. Better, as several say, is to use a series R per series string - souse 3 x 68 Ohms - one per string.